# Count number of occurrences at end of string

Tags: r

I want to count how many commas are at the end of a string with a regex:

```
x <- c("w,x,,", "w,x,", "w,x", "w,x,,,")
```

I'd like to get:

```
[1] 2 1 0 3
```

This gives:

```
library(stringi)
stringi::stri_count_regex(x, ",+$")
## [1] 1 1 0
```

Because I'm using a quantifier but don't know how to count actual number of times single character was repeated at end.

Comment: I would just do `nchar(gsub("[^,]", "", x))`, though not sure if this valid per your requirements. I think you maybe need to make an example where the commas aren't at the end too?

Comment: Building off @DavidArenburg's comment, what about `nchar(x) - nchar(gsub(",+$", "", x))`?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns nice, I'll add that to my answer if its fine with you

Comment: @DavidArenburg go for it, though I'm not sure which is more efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `"match.length"` attribute within the `regexpr` seem to get the job done (-1 is used to distinguish no match from zero-width matches such as lookaheads)

```
attr(regexpr(",+$", x), "match.length")
## [1] 2  1 -1  3
```

---

Another option (with contribution from @JasonAizkalns) would be

```
nchar(x) - nchar(gsub(",+$", "", x))
## [1] 2 1 0 3
```

---

Or using `stringi` package combined with `nchar` while specifying `, keepNA = TRUE` (this way no matches will be specified as `NA`s)

```
library(stringi)
nchar(stri_extract_all_regex(x, ",+$"), keepNA = TRUE)
## [1] 2  1 NA  3
```

Comment: Nice! I wonder why *length* is '-1' for no match though. When would the length be '0' then?

Comment: I think 0 is for lookaheads?

Comment: yea lookaheads are zero-width `attr(regexpr("(?=,)", x, perl=TRUE),"match.length")`

Comment: @Tyler, added additional possible stringi solution.